# How can i get fast response from Web purify API for image moderation

Tags: php, api

I am using the following script of web purify for image moderation

```
<?php
function image_purification($fire_response){
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,Array());
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://im-api1.webpurify.com/services/rest/?method=webpurify.live.imgcheck&api_key=".$api_key."&format=json&imgurl=".$firebase_image_url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$fire_response  =   curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($fire_response);           
}
```

when i run this curl in postman its  take more  time for approved image. I want to get approved or decline status fast in second.. can it get response at one time call api.

https://www.webpurify.com/image-moderation/

please give me any solution to get fast response of  whole status of approved image .

Thanks:

Answer (score 0):

You are submitting your request to our live image moderation team with has response times of up to 5 minutes.

If you require real-time results you can submit your images using the webpurify.aim.imgcheck method. This method will submit the image to our AIM service that will return the probability the image contains nudity.

Documentation can be found here: https://www.webpurify.com/image-moderation/documentation/methods/aim-imgcheck/

If you have any questions you can email us at support@webpurify.com